# KMongo creates multiple connections

Tags: mongodb, kmongo

I started working on a KMongo project in Kotlin, though when I connect to my database KMongo creates 2 connections, instead of one [(look at the image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu9DD.png). Does somebody know why?

My class to connect with the database

```
object Mongo {
    lateinit var connectionString: String
    lateinit var database: String

    private lateinit var mongo: MongoDatabase

    fun connect() {
        val client = KMongo.createClient(connectionString)
        mongo = client.getDatabase(database)
    }

    fun get(collection: String): CoroutineCollection<Document> {
        return this.mongo.getCollection(collection).coroutine
    }

}

fun database(database: Mongo.() -> Unit) = Mongo.apply(database)
```

The main class

```
fun main() {
    Thread {
        while (true) {
        }
    }.start()

    database {
        connectionString = "mongodb://username:password@host:port/test?w=majority"
        database = "Test"
    }.also { it.connect() }
}
```

For the dependencies I used

- kmongo-async
- kmongo-coroutine

Comment: That quite probably depends on the connection string.

Comment: My connection String has the following pattern:
`mongodb://username:password@host:port/test?w=majority`

Comment: Is the mongod configured with a replica set name?

Comment: No I don't think so. Would you set this up in the connection string too?

Comment: If you are connecting to a replica set, it is normal for the driver to open one connection to discover/monitor the nodes, and others for data operations

Comment: I'm using the free atlas tier. From what I read I think I don't use a replica set. Maybe I'm misunderstanding that but I also checked the connection String template here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/. There the replica set string looks very different from mine too.

Comment: Atlas doesn't offer single nodes, so it is definitely a replica set.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Well, that clarifies my question. Thank you very much!